# multi insert in condition into 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, insert

there's a trx_log table that record any activity I/O. 
in create activity form, there's 3 input but with condition not always fulfill, sometime only 1 input executed. sometimes two due to only 1 input executed, so it must be only 1 recorded in trx_log table.but it's not. all of input recorded into trx_log table while only 1 input filled and the others is not. 
i just want only an input that fulfilled can recorded.

```
if ($id_kons1>0) {
    mysql_query("insert into trx_kons values('','".$_REQUEST['id_kons1']."','$trx_dateout','','$jumlah1','','','','1','')");
} elseif ($id_kons2>0) {
    mysql_query("insert into trx_kons values('','".$_REQUEST['id_kons2']."','$trx_dateout','','$jumlah2','','','','1','')");
} elseif ($id_kons3>0) {
    mysql_query("insert into trx_kons values('','".$_REQUEST['id_kons3']."','$trx_dateout','','$jumlah3','','','','1','')");
}
```

please help me, im in stuck.

Comment: your question is not clear! what is that you want with these insert statements

Comment: where do you set values to $id_kons1, $id_kons2...

Comment: $id_kons1, $id_kons2, $id_kons3 is a name of selectable input.

Comment: $jumlah1, $jumlah2, $jumlah3 is a number of input. 
maybe it just like warehouse application, records an input and output.
sometimes 1 input and sometimes 2 or 3 input in one time. because the form is enable to do like that

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear ;-/. I assume that you want up to three rows to be inserted depending on what input is filled in on the form. make them three separate if statements to do that.

If nothing else, this answer will help you to make it clear what you do want to happen with input.

```
if ($id_kons1>0) {
    mysql_query("insert into trx_kons values('','".$_REQUEST['id_kons1']."','$trx_dateout','','$jumlah1','','','','1','')");
}

if ($id_kons2>0) {
    mysql_query("insert into trx_kons values('','".$_REQUEST['id_kons2']."','$trx_dateout','','$jumlah2','','','','1','')");
}

if ($id_kons3>0) {
    mysql_query("insert into trx_kons values('','".$_REQUEST['id_kons3']."','$trx_dateout','','$jumlah3','','','','1','')");
}
```